# Springboot data how to make a Query correctly managing NumberLong?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I'm storing elements with a Int64 field in MongoDb. I'm generating a value using all the bigfield and real 64 bits values.

Document looks like
{
   fileds...
   messageUid : -3130564683773456202
}

No problem to write this long value with springboot-data.

Now I want to make a search on this value and SpringBoot-data returns nothing ...

```
findMessagesByMessageUid(long _messageUid) returns nothing.
findMessagesByMessageUid(Long _messageUid) returns nothing.
```

I've try in mongoShell directly
1 - find({messageUid: -3130564683773456202})
This is not working because the shell transform the number into a double and at end the value does not match exactly

2 - find({messageUid: NumberLong(-3130564683773456202)})
This is not working because the value is too large (there is a limit, I read that somewhere)

3 - find({messageUid: NumberLong("-3130564683773456202")})
This is working correctly

So I would like to know How to write the 3rd version of the query with SpringBoot-data

I've try different things around

```
@Query("{messageUid:NumberLong(?0)}")
public Message findMessageByMessageUid( long messageUid  );
```

=> JSON Parse exception on bootup

```
@Query("{messageUid:NumberLong(?0)}")
public Message findMessageByMessageUid( String messageUid  );
```

=> JSON Parse exception on bootup

Basically we can't use NumberLong in the @Query string.

I also tried

```
public Message findMessageByMessageUid( String messageUid  );
```

=> Return no matching document

Can someone tells me how can we make a working search on NumberLong with Spring-data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Query("{ 'messageUid' : NumberLong(?0) }")
public Message findMessageByMessageUid( Long messageUid  );
```

Comment: Not working : same Parsing issue : Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ 'messageUid' : NumberLong("_param_0") }
                  ^
 at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:301) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]

Comment: What is `messageUid` data type?

Comment: It is Int64 data type

Comment: You should use `Long` type in your repository method like this `public Message findMessageByMessageUid( Long messageUid  );` From your error in comment, I believe you are using `String`. Please confirm

Comment: With Long I've got no value, exactly like with long.

Comment: @disk91 - Did you found the solution?